# Expect Script - bash script file not found

Tags: bash, macos, expect

My expect script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

#I tried replacing sh - with bash -s still no positive results
spawn ssh xxxx@yyyy "sh -" < test.sh
expect "password: "
send "zzzzz\r"
expect "$ "
```

This command works well if executed in the terminal

```
ssh xxxx@yyyy "sh -" < test.sh
```

But if I execute it via `expect` script; it fails.

This is the output if I execute it via the expect script. May I know where I am going wrong

```
bash: test.sh: No such file or directory
```

P.S : Yes, the file exists and the credentials are right.

Comment: Did you try giving the absolute path of the script `test.sh`?

Comment: `expect` is not `shell`, it doesn't process the `<`. Your expect script need to read the `test.sh` file and `send` it.

Comment: @Inian : Yes I did try that and the result was the same

Comment: @Dummy00001 : yes indeed that was the issue. I will post an answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expect script was unable to read the contents of the file, that was the issue. Solved it by reading the contents of the file and passing that variable instead of the file name,

```
set fh [open test.sh r]
set contents [read $fh]
close $fh
```

and replacing the `sh-` with `bash -c '$contents'`

Thank you everyone for the valuable comments.